# Fatal error while taking snapshot of view: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller, snapshot

My app crashes when I take a snapshot of the current view, which is a `UIViewController` displaying a photo generated by a `UIPageViewController`.

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {        
    super.viewDidLoad()
    Utils.getImageAsync(photo!.url!, completion: { (photoView) -> () in            
        //Create Basic View Components
        self.view.addSubview(self.createHeaderView())
        self.view.addSubview(self.createScrollView())            
        //Create Blurred View
        self.blurredBgImage!.image = self.blurWithGPUImage(self.takeSnapshotOfView(self.view)) // fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
    })

 }
```

Why could cause that?

Comment: `self.blurredBgImage` cannot be unwrapped because it's nil

Comment: But even if I add an image manually like this `self.blurredBgImage!.image = UIImage(named: "profile-bg")!` I still get the same error

Comment: You're right, I should have put ? instead of !, now it's working, thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using "!" you are force unwrapping a nil optional.

You can use a force unwrap "!" if you know the optional does not have a nil value. If you force unwrap an optional that contains a nil value it will cause the crash you are experiencing.

The ? unwrapping prevents this. Basically it checks "if X = nil". If so ignore/do nothing. Preventing the crash.

I hope my jibberish makes sense. It does in my head :)